# When i try to name my array i get an error but if i don't name it its fine for some reason

Tags: arrays, json

I am trying to use json to hold a simple array of customers and I want to be able to loop through it later. My problem is when I give the array a name i.e. "var customs" it throws an error and says "Expected a JSON object, array or literal" however when there is no name it's fine.

So something like this is fine:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"John",
    "address":"210 downing street",
    "phone":1158765309, "email":"Customer1@gmail.com",
    "BD":"12121990" 
  }
]
```

and something like this is throwing an error

```
var Customer = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"John",
    "address":"210 downing street",
    "phone":1158765309, "email":"Customer1@gmail.com",
    "BD":"12121990" 
  }
]
```

What I've gathered from the documentation and W3 this should be fine but I'm new to json so any help to understand what's going wrong is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That's because the second one is not a json object, but is a js (right?) code, when you assigning the object to variable. JSON itself does not have any variables support.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know about JSON, you cannot name the root element. The root array or object should be unnamed. Also, `var` or `=` do not exist in JSON syntax. You are probably trying to do something like this.

```
{  
    "Customers": [
        {
        "id":1,
        "name":"John",
        "address":"210 downing street",
        "phone":1158765309, "email":"Customer1@gmail.com",
        "BD":"12121990" 
         }
    ]
}
```